# Python Compare item from list of list by Issubset or other method

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist

I would like to see if all items from one list of list (List A) that appears from another list of list (List B - a full list), then save the return true or false to a list.

For example, here are two lists (list of list) below

```
List A : [ [1,2],[3,4],[8,9] ]

List B : [ [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7],[8,10] ]
```

Expected Result

```
 Result List : [[True,False,False]
```

Comment: Can you explain your result with correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
A = [ [1,2],[3,4],[8,9] ]
B = [ [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7],[8,10] ]
result = []
for x,y in zip(A, B):
    if all(e in y for e in x):
        result.append(True)
    else:
        result.append(False)
```

which produces a list as the following:

```
[True, False, False]
```

The code uses `zip()` function which pairs corresponding items from the two lists together.

Also, the line `all(e in y for e in x)` is the essential part of the code. It checks if *all* elements in the first sub-list of A are in the first sub-list B, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip()` along with `issubset()` method on `set` as follows:

```
[True if set(x).issubset(set(y)) else False for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

Performance wise I don't think this is better that ammar's answer. But this is a one liner ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using [issubset()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects)

```
A = [[1,2],[3,4],[8,9]]
B = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7],[8,10]]
result = [True if set(i[0]).issubset(i[1]) else False for i in list(zip(A,B))]
print(result)
# 158 µs ± 14.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Output:

```
[True, False, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `list-comprehension` and `zip`:

```
a = [ [1,2],[3,4],[8,9] ]

b = [ [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7],[8,10] ]

result = [True if set(i[0]).issubset(set(i[1])) else False for i in zip(a,b) ]
print(result)
```

**Output :**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
[True, False, False]
```